# How to set the coordinates to which a window gets minimized to

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, windows, winapi

I was trying to overlap two windows one over another to overcome airspace issue in my WPF application. I need the two windows to move together and resize together and require all animations to be as it is (I mean the window restore, maximize and minimize animations).

I was able to move and resize the window together but since I `use WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` my background window is not minimized on to taskbar, it goes to the bottom left corner of the Desktop.

Here is a sample screenshot:

Before minimize, the window looks like :

[image: Before maximize]

After minimize the window looks like :

[image: After maximize]

Since the window gets minimized to desktop instead of taskbar I decided to change the position to which window is minimized to, if I could minimize both window to same coordinates then the animation will be smooth ,once minimize is complete I will hide the background window.

Is there any way to set the point to which window is minimized to. **Some apps like Rocket Dock  was able to do it**, so it is possible, but how can I do it.

**Note : The blur is drawn into the background Window**

Comment: You position a Window using the Window.Top and Window.Left properties. You can use the Window.Topmost property to control layering. If your windows have a kind of a primary/secondary relationship you can use the Window.Owner property to manifest such. This way for exaple minimizing the owner would also minimize all owned Window instances. Minimizing/maximizing is always referring to the default Windows minimize/maximize behavior. But you can overrride the default WindowChrome to implement a custom behavior by modifying the action of the chrome buttons.

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68548769/3141792) that shows how you can override the default window chrome.

Comment: It's not about overriding the default window style, setting owner window also does the same thing it will minimize to desktop if i use WS_EX_NOACTIVE, The background window uses Windows.UI.Composition to draw acrylic, so i cannot draw any wpf controls on it, if i need to draw anything means i need to create a seperate foreground window and draw controls on it. i resize the background window by handling WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message and use setWindowPos().

Comment: I tried using some shell api to remove the icon from taskbar and alt+tab, and this occurs : https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/72641365/130594549-a0095b94-6318-4449-89aa-9d4213e02a30.mp4

Comment: the flickering is because of screen recorder, the position to which the window minimize is like (-3200,-3200) issue that was in Windows NT

Comment: I slow down dwm animations to see where the window is moving to